# How to implement tooltip on a listbox items

Tags: c#

I have a standard ListBox in a C# application. What I would like to achieve is when a user places the mouse over any item, a tooltip appear for each of the respective item. Any suggestions as to how this could be to achieve?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Take a peek at the related links at the bottom right.

Comment: So many questions I don't even know where to begin.